# Objective-C: File Manager, trouble deleting a file

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager

I have the following method, which takes in the name of a file as a string, then appends it to the path that is declared outside of the method.

```
-(BOOL)deleteFile:(NSString *)filename{

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *myPathDocs = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
NSLog(@"[deleteFile] *myPathsDocs: %@", myPathDocs);

NSLog(@"[deleteFile] about to delete file");
//delete file
BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:myPathDocs error:NULL];
NSLog(@"[deleteFile] success? %@", success);


return success;
```

It deletes the file from the directory, but then the program crashes without returning, or even making it to the

```
NSLog(@"[deleteFile] success? %@", success);
```

Any ideas?  I think it may be something obvious that I am just not seeing, but I've looked through it many times, and everything seems to be in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `success` is of type BOOL and the `%@` format specifier is for objects. So when NSLog tries to use your boolean (which is either 1 or 0) as a pointer, it crashes with a segmentation fault. Use

```
NSLog(@"Success: %@", success ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

instead.

Comment: ahhhhhh haha thanks that works!  It never crossed my mind to check the Log statement.

Comment: No problem. You can always use a debugger for errors like this. You can also display a bool using the '%d' specifier.

Comment: Thanks!  I am fairly new to Objective-C / Xcode and have I been doing all my debugging with NSLog, which ironically was the bug this time haha